# "rails new project_name" creates empty project directory on OSX

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos

I am trying to create a new rails project but get the error below and my new project directory is empty! I found [an issue on the rails github repo](https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/6868) but the solution they suggest is to remove spaces in the project directory. I don't have spaces in my project directory, so this solution doesn't apply. If I missed something and can provide anymore information please let me know. Any help is very much appreciated!

```
$ rails new bookmarks_app
  create  
  Could not find "README" in any of your source paths. Your current source paths are: 
  /Users/Jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates
$ ls
bookmarks_app
$ ls bookmarks_app/
$ pwd
  /Users/Jared/Desktop/Sandbox/website
$ rails --version
  Rails 3.2.8
$ ruby --version
  ruby 1.9.3p286 (2012-10-12 revision 37165) [x86_64-darwin12.2.0]
```

Operating System: OSX

Comment: What do you get when you do `ls /Users/Jared/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/railties-3.2.8/lib/rails/generators/rails/app/templates`? (or whatever the Mac equivalent is for listing directories) It should have the basic structure of a rails app there.

Comment: I get the message: "No such file or directory"

Comment: Did you copy-paste the command I wrote? There seems to be an extra character (the rectangle after "generators/"). You should copy the directory it's looking for directly from the error message or just browse there in a finder window.

Comment: Ah there was a space hiding in there. This time it worked and the directory is empty. Any idea on how I can tell rails to update and get those template values?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mixed something up during my install because I was trying to use macports and rvm without quite understanding how they work. I was able to reinstall ruby and rails, and it is now working.

Remove old Ruby files/install:

```
sudo rm -rf ~/.rvm
brew uninstall ruby
sudo rm /usr/local/bin/ruby
```

Install Ruby and Rails:

```
brew install ruby
gem install bundler
gem install rails
```